# Get JSON Data in multiple components using reactjs and redux

Tags: json, reactjs, api, redux, jsx

I would like to show data from a single API to different components as I want to hit the API only once and distribute the data to multiple small components. I know I can do this by using redux state but not sure how to do it. Need your help to achieve this. Below is the code done so far.

**homepage/index.js**

```
import SlidingBanner from './banner/BannerList';
import Celebslider from './celebrityslider/CelebSlider';

class HomePage extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
                <SlidingBanner />
                <anotherslider />
            </div>  
          );
        }
      }

    export default HomePage;
```

**BannerList.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { itemsFetchData } from '../../../actions/items';

class BannerList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        let bannerArray = [];
        let banner = this.props.items.banner
        for (let key in banner) {
            bannerArray.push(banner[key]);
            return (
                <div>
            <Slider {...slidersettings}>
            {this.props.items.banner.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <img src={item.image_url} className="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </Slider>        
            </div>
            );
        }
        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }

        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }
        return (null);
    }
}

BannerList.propTypes = {
    fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    hasErrored: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
        hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BannerList);
```

**anotherslider.js**

```
Now in this file, i want to fetch another array of objects or object from the same API. 

I tried to mount the API in container component but did not worked, I hope i am doing some mistake. Please correct.
```

Comment: Read about `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`
https://gist.github.com/markerikson/121c77a01c453466361a9c6434a08620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call data in both of the sliders, you have 2 ways to handle it.

1. Make your redux requests in `HomePage.js` component and bind the data to the other components.
2. When you get the data on `BannerList.js` component, your state will be updated. Just add the redux connection to your `anotherslider.js` component and get data when updated.

   ```
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {
           items: state.items,
           hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
           isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
       };
   };

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeList);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any example for the first option. ( Make your redux requests in HomePage.js component and bind the data to the other components. ) ??

Comment: @user1328423 I made a simple example, please check it. https://codesandbox.io/s/4zo2mj09o7

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But the example is showing error.

`Line 16:  'items' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 16:  'hasErrored' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 16:  'isLoading' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 24:  'items' is not defined       no-undef` 

This line is having syntax error also

`{items, hasErrored, isLoading} = this.props;`

Comment: Ok I was able to change it to the following in render method and that worked. `const {items, hasErrored, isLoading} = this.props;`

Comment: @user1328423 I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch data in ***anotherslider.js*** file you must connect reducer to class/function inside it as well as you are making it in ***BannerList.js*** file.
Now before render call `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function and you will get your data here.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all these options, you can also use react's Context API as Provider/consumer to distribute your data among small components... this will save you passing props to all small components and directly access the value in component using Context.Consumer .. moreover if you do not want to store this state in global redux store, context API will save you from it...

Comment: Thanks for the info, Sure I will look at it